# How do I jump to a section of a page in PHP like a search box?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Ok, so I have a simple page that displays the output of a MySQL table. The contents are large, and it is my intention for people to search through it.

The issue is that the database does not index it by highest rank, but rather by order created.

The page orders it for me, and then I use a cheap counter in a loop to rank players.

I already have the anchoring set up, you can search by Rank, SteamID, RP Name, and Wallet.

However, I need the search box. Currently, only SteamID is important.

http://www.triggergaming.net/stats.php is the page. I have one that currently works, but it isn't quite what i want. I want it to not require a page refresh. I currently use `header()` as my means of searching by placing that at the top of the page,

```
<?php if ($_POST["SteamID"]){
    header("Location: stats.php#".$_POST["SteamID"]);
exit;
}?>
```

The rank is stored as `$count`, steamid as `$row[steamID]`, rpname as `$row[rpname]` and wallet as `$row[wallet]`

EDIT: Now that I think of it, Wallet is not a unique variable, and there can (and will) be duplicates. So I won't index that.

Comment: you can't use PHP to do that without refreshing the page

Comment: Do you mean this? http://www.myhtmltutorials.com/jump.html or this? http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/jquery_internal_animation_scrolling/, or do you mean like when you post? You will need jquery if its on a post

Comment: I mean like, type in a SteamID, and goto the section of the page

Answer (score 3):

If you dont require a page refresh use javascript, jquery in order to construct anchor HTML like this:

With Jquery

HTML

```
Search ID <input type="text" id="searchid"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" id="search-button"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#search-button').on('click',function(ev){
    var steamID = $('#searchid').val();
    location.href='#'+steamID;
});
```

I rewrite a functional version with jquery and a little bit of data:
http://jsfiddle.net/Uyt7a/1/
This actually works.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, I corrected a typo of yours (seachid should have been searchid) but nothing happens.

Comment: I rewrite with jquery and post a jsfiddle with data from the example url you post.